# install samba client (smbclient) without the daemon

Tags: yum, samba

On Centos 6.10, if I try

```
yum install samba-client
```

I get also these dependencies

```
samba-common
samba-winbind
samba-winbind-clients
```

If I try `cifs-utils`, I also get a dependency on `samba-winbind`.

The Linux host has to use network shares provided by Windows servers, so it doesn't need the daemon provided by `samba-winbind`.

How can I install the minimal requirements to run `smbclient`?

Comment: Do you just need to be able to mount Windows shares on the machine? What OS or distro are you using?

Comment: Centos 6.10. Cannot upgrade, intranet legacy server.

Comment: Answer the question on what you are trying to do. Do you just need to connect to Windows shares? Is it printers that you want to communicate with? Are you trying to remotely connect to a Windows machine? If you are so convinced that you need `samba-client`, then just `yum install samba-client`. There is nothing that you can do to prevent the system from installing the dependencies. The package needs them and that's why they are called dependencies.

Comment: Nasir, you asked me the distro: it is written in my question. You wrote an answer *yum install cifs-utils* that has the same problems as *yum install samba-client". Now you delete your answer and downvote me... NO COMMENT.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. It was downvoted long before I read it probably because it's not clear what you are trying to do or what the problem is. I asked you what you are trying to do that makes you think that you need `samba-client`. If your problem is that it's installing dependencies, then that's not a problem and means that the package manager is functioning exactly as it should. If you aren't going to answer a simple question on what you are trying to do, then how do you expect to get the help that you need?

Comment: I don't see the problem here. Are you saying that you disagree with the package manager on what dependencies need to be pulled in? What makes you think those dependencies are installing a daemon?

Comment: The daemon for `samba` which is known as `smb.service` is provided by the `samba` package which is not one of the dependencies that `yum` is trying to install.

Comment: You could possibly allow the dependencies to run, and then disable the `winbind` daemon. Interestingly on Debian there's no such dependency (that I can see)

Comment: @roaima I know but it is a ugly solution. Your statement about Debian rafforces my conviction it is a fault by the authors of the Centos package.

Comment: @Nasir Riley You didn't read carefully my question: *smb.service* doesn't even exist on Centos 6. Your comment is off topic.

Comment: @Massimo Yes, it does exist on CentOS and is provided by the `samba` package. If the system that you are using doesn't have that package installed, then that just means that your system doesn't have it. It doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. What you have clearly shown is that you know very little about CentOS or Linux in general especially considering your failure to understand dependencies and the package management system and your terrible method for getting `samba-client` onto the machine beforehand. Whoever owns that machine needs to find someone to manage it who is actually competent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes thanks to the dialogue with other users, comparing two unsatisfactory solutions, the correct solution is found.

I discover after blocking the installation of *samba-client*

```
/etc/yum.conf
```

> exclude=samba-*

if you issue

```
yum install samba-client
```

yum will find the alternative package *samba4-client*, not depending on the samba daemon.

Bingo!

---

This is the right solution for Centos 6.10:

```
yum install samba4-client
```

The package samba-client installs version 3.6, requiring the daemon bloatware.

The package samba4-client installs version 4.2, client only.
Availabe on the official *centos* repository.

Comment: A dependency isn't bloatware. It has files that are needed by another package. That's why it's called a dependency.

Comment: Bloatware. Indeeed in *samba4-client* they fixed it and remove the dependency.

Answer (score 4):

In Debian, `smbclient` is in its [own package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/smbclient) (along with other command-line utilities), so no need for the `winbind` dependency. In CentOS 6, it's lumped in with all the Samba client-side tools, some of which do require `samba-winbind`. Therefore, you cannot install `samba-client` without pulling in the dependency on `samba-winbind`.

My recommendation, therefore, would be to accept this unwanted dependency. The `winbind` daemon is stopped and disabled by default so there's nothing that needs to be done after installing it.

In CentOS 7 and CentOS 8, `samba-winbind` and `samba-winbind-clients` aren't dependencies for `samba-client` and it can be installed without them but you are using CentOS 6.

Comment: Hi Roaima. Thanks for your attention. See my update on *smbclient* : it depends only on *libwbclient.so*   What about download the RPMs and extract only the library, using yum tools?

Comment: @Massimo I don't run CentOS so I don't know what the effect of this would be. As I say, my recommendation would be simply to accept the dependencies and move on.

Comment: There isn't *one size fits all*. Your solution isn't good for us: *samba-winbind* creates a new system daemon.

Comment: One that's not active

Comment: Yes I knew. We have policies about installed daemons. Pls don't push too hard for your answer :-)